# Iterate through 2D array and get average of its for neighboring cells

Tags: java

What I am trying to do is iterate through the `2D array` to find an `average`.

The values in the `middle` must be calculated as an average of 4 sides `(Top,Bottom,Left,Right and recalculated)`. I have to find the values of the four sides of the current index and replace the current index with that number. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
final public class Matrix {
private final int M;             // number of rows
private final int N;             // number of columns
private final double[][] data;   // M-by-N array

// create M-by-N matrix of 0's
public Matrix(int M, int N) {
    this.M = M;
    this.N = N;
    data = new double[M][N];
}

// create matrix based on 2d array
public Matrix(double[][] data) {
    M = data.length;
    N = data[0].length;
    this.data = new double[M][N];
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                this.data[i][j] = data[i][j];
}

// copy constructor
private Matrix(Matrix A) { this(A.data); }



// print matrix to standard output
public void show() {
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
            System.out.printf("%.1f ", data[i][j]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}



// test client
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] d = { { 22.5,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,51 }, 
                     { 15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,72 },
                     { 15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,72 },
                     { 15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,72 },
                     { 15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,72 },
                     { 15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,72 },
                     { 15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,72 },
                     { 15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,72 },
                     { 15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,72 },
                     { 45,75,75,75,75,75,75,75,75,73.5 }

    };


    Matrix D = new Matrix(d);
    D.show(); 
    System.out.println();



}
}
```

Comment: Having a hard time understanding your question.  i.e. what happens at index[0][0] b/c there aren't four sides?  Additionally, where does recalculation start and stop?  Please clarify.

Comment: At [0][0] i just hard coded the average of its two neighboring sides, which are (30+15/2)

Comment: The recalculation has to stop when the total grid error is less than 5.0

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is just a really simplistic blur operation, basically a form of [box blur](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_blur). Any operation where you take an NxN submatrix for every pixel in an image and multiply it by another NxN matrix is called a [kernel convolution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)). Rosetta Code has a good example in Java on [this page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Image_convolution).

If you can use AWT, the Java standard library already has [`ConvolveOp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ConvolveOp.html) built in.